# Retrieving data from web browser's download manager using java

Tags: java

I want to try creating a program that can automate the storing of web address that is available on every downloaded file on a web browser.

My problem is I don't know where to start.

What am I planning to do is just save all the downloaded file's web addresses in a excel file.

[Sample image using google chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UML8n.jpg)

Comment: What programming experience do you have?  And what is it that you are unsure of?  How to access that information from the browser?  How to convert the information to an excel file format once you have it?  What libraries / tools you need to perform the specified function?  How to go about designing a more specific functional specification in the first place?  Something else?

Comment: I just have to retrieve those data from the web browser. and it looks like I can retrieve it without coding based on the answers below. but i dont know how to do it in windows

Answer (score 0):

I think Firefox stores the download history in the `places.sqlite` file in your `Profile` folder. You would need to open and read that file, but you probably can't while Firefox is open (it has the file open).

http://kb.mozillazine.org/Places.sqlite

From there, you can process the data in your Java app and then write an Excel file, perhaps using Apache POI (the Java API for Microsoft Documents)

https://poi.apache.org/

Answer (score 0):

Where and how, download history is stored varies from browser to browser . In case of Chrome on Mac it is store in the path 
`~/Library/Application\ Support/Google/Chrome/Default/DownloadMetadata`
 as `SQLite` format.

You need to write an application to parse the data and create xls

Comment: how about in windows?